# I did bring/brought this up

Tags: word-choice, tense, auxiliary-verbs

I brought this up. - 0

I did bring this up. - 1

I did brought this up. - 2

Is it ever acceptable to use (2)? I have a vague memory from high school that the second tense is something *rarely* used to emphasize or exaggerate the idea, stronger than the previous 2 (in this order). Example:

Are you silly? Don't you remember? I *did* brought this up.

I also have a feeling this is a lesser known grammar fact that few people are aware of, so I am afraid that if I *do* use it, the larger public will frown.

That said, it's also possible that I am very wrong.

Please, input ideally from natives or C2 speakers. I consider myself very advanced, but I have, however, been having this doubt.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: See the duplicate.  In short: Never use (2). It is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

"I did brought this up" is grammatically wrong.

"I brought this up" and "I did bring this up" are both correct. "I did bring this up" is much more insistent that you actually brought this up.

For example, someone accuses you "you didn't bring this up, and the company lost $10,000 because of this mistake". You would say "I *did* bring this up" with strong emphasis on "did", and not "I brought this up".